# e parameter in javascript event callback

Tags: javascript

It's been a long time i want to learn more about this `e` parameter we can catch in events callbacks, most of the time to call `e.preventDefault()`.

I am wondering what we can access with this variable, it would be very interesting to directly get the element concerned by the event, for example:

```
<button class="active" onclick="callback()">Click me</button>

<script>
  function callback(e) {
    if (e.className == "active") {
      //proocess...
    }
  }
</script>
```

Is it possible ? What functionalities can we use with this `e` parameter ?

Thanks !

Comment: This is what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the element concerned from the event object, just call:

```
e.target
```

and I think Microsoft handle it differently, so:

```
e.srcElement
```

would work in their case

Answer (score 0):

Catch `e` in your console and check it out yourself!

```
function callback(e) {

    console.log(e);
}
```